# How to securely suggest passwords that are easy to remember?

Tags: security, passwords, generator

I want to suggest automatically generated passwords for users who are registering or changing their password. How to approach this?

First of all, the reason for offering generated passwords is to try prevent users from using weak passwords (e.g. `monkey`). I could (and still will) enforce certain restrictions on passwords: they must contain both lowercase and uppercase letters, numbers and punctuation, and must be long enough. Enforcing these kinds of rules still leads to poor patterns, such as simply appending the required characters to the original weak password (e.g. `Monkey3!`). Also other common patterns exist (e.g. `m0nk3y`).

Totally random passwords (e.g. `I1ZkFdt5OOX35Rp` or `B13v}lo90m%~zrY`) are hard to remember. They usually end up written on a piece of paper. If given the choice, users will back to their own weak password when confronted with a monstrosity like this.

But, simple passwords can be strong, if long enough ([yes, relevant xkcd](http://xkcd.com/936/)). I'd like to generate passwords like these, so that they're easy to remember while still strong:

```
MooseCoolSuggestionDude
RegisterAmericaFoolDinner
```

Assuming I have a list of words for this stored somewhere, that storage could be compromised. Whoever got the list could generate all possible combinations that I'm offering to my users for use as a password. So it's a potential security risk.

I thought about some added randomisation. What if I added random numbers and punctuation to the generated passwords, e.g.

```
Moose5CoolSuggestion-Dude
Register.America31FoolDinner
```

Would this work as a secure way to offer memorable, automatically generated passwords? Any other ideas?

Comment: It is not directly relevant, but I think can give you some interesting ideas http://ss64.com/passwords/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, this is a dead end unless you are making a site specifically for generating passwords. In short, this is more of a person problem than a development one.

From a security standpoint, I don't like this because you have the plaintext version of my password. I don't care that you are going to hash it, I just know that you have a plaintext version if I choose one, and you could choose not to hash it. I know that this is really always an issue, but it would make me feel even more uneasy about it. I don't know how "random" this password you've chosen for me is. Maybe everyone gets the same list? The only time I want the site I am using to generate my password is possibly for temporary passwords if I get locked out of my account.

Additionally, for you to share this password with me, you must show the text on my screen, which may or may not be a good thing from a user experience standpoint. If you decide to do this, just be mindful that I may not want my password displayed publicly, and some users may unknowingly expose their password to an onlooker. Hide it by default.

I would choose a solution that involves some of these things:

- Don't give the user insane requirements for your password. It doesn't make great passwords, and it is frustrating from the user's point of view.
- Show some example passwords that are good (just don't let them use the example ones)
- Set up [multi-factor authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication)
- Indicate in some way (see the first UX link below) how strong their password is.

#### relevant links

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12287/how-can-i-promote-good-password-practices-in-an-organization-that-doesnt-curren
- https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16433/what-is-the-best-way-to-inspire-users-to-choose-strong-password
- https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35304/telling-users-passwords-dont-match-and-arent-strong-enough

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Gray's excellent anwswer, I'm firmly in the belief that a website password should be difficult to remember: http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/03/only-secure-password-is-one-you-cant.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of https://passwordcreator.org/ which has the functionality that you are looking for.   In addition to the XKCD style passwords with several words, the site also generates "fake words" and traditional randoms strings of numbers and letters.

You can embed an `iframe` on your website to give your users password suggestions right on your account creation page.   Here is a screen shot:

[image: Random password suggestions]

The code for doing so is:

```
<h3>Suggested Passwords:</h3>
<iframe src="//passwordcreator.org/suggest.html#securitylevel=good"
style="width:355px;height:193px;"></iframe>
```

The `iframe` can be resized as small as 100x100 pixels.   At smaller widths, it only generates shorter passwords consisting of random numbers and letters.   When it is taller, it shows more passwords.  Five password strength levels are available: "poor", "subpar", "good", "great", "amazing".

The passwords are generated by JavaScript using modern browsers' secure random number generator functionality.    The passwords never travel over a network or are seen by any computer other than the user's client computer that generates them.   The site supports HTTPS for additional security.

Answer (score -1):

This is just an idea, you can build on top of it (in PHP):

```
<?php

function newRandPass() {
    $wordList = array('Moose','Cool','Suggestion',
                      'Dude','Register','America',
                      'Fool','Dinner','Hello');
    $passWords = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $passWords[] = $wordList[mt_rand(0, sizeof($wordList))];
    }
    return implode(mt_rand(1,999), $passWords);
}

echo newRandPass();

?>
```

Outputs:

```
Dinner455Hello455Moose
Suggestion495Register495Hello
Fool590Dude590Cool
Dude956Register956Hello
```

Comment: Using `mt_rand` is insecure.